# error converting nvarcher to numeric when using between in where statement in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008

i have a simple query which is:

In the Where statement i need to be able to say between two paramteres

OPI_LAL_LOTNOENT_00.REEL between
                             @from
                             and @To

if i choose to use the above in the where statement i get the error converting nvarcher to numeric.

If anyone knows of a better way to do this by all means tell me, or could you tell me how to convert the nvarcher to a number whilst still being able to use between

All i want to be able to do is allow the user to choose between 2 values which they would enter themselves when running a report, for example

from = 10
to = 100

this would only bring back results where OPI_LAL_LOTNOENT_00.REEL result is between and including 10 and 100

Answer (score 0):

I would change the Data type for the Parameters from and To, from Text to Integer.  Then the users will only be able to enter valid numbers.

Comment: i cant even get to the parameter defining stage the query fails with the error converting nvarcher to numeric when i execute the query

Comment: What do you mean "the parameter defining stage"?  Are you using the BIDS/ Visual Studio Query Designer?  That can be a waste of time.

Comment: i am using report builder 3.0, within report builder you have to define each parameters with @reel for example